# Size-advantageousness of policy?

Tags: nouns, expression-choice

Suppose some government policy tends to help large communities rather than small ones.

I want to describe this as a noun.

Will *"size-advantageousness of policy"* be a good choice to describe that?

Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: If somebody said "size-advantageousness of policy" to me, I wouldn't have any idea what they were talking about.

Comment: A *policy principally for the benefit of large communities* ?

Comment: A *majoritarian* policy?

Answer (score 3):

I would try:

> The *bias of the policy toward large communities* is such that...

Admittedly, this construction requires the prepositional phrase after it for clarity/specificity, but it can be used in the same noun phrase template that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to it as:

> - A policy that discriminates against small communities.

Comment: OP wants a noun.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use the word [***discrimination***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discrimination) which means:

> the practice of **unfairly treating a person or group of people**
>   differently from other people or groups of people

In your example, you could use:

> The **policy discrimination** against small communities...

or

> The **discriminating policy** against small communities...

[Merriam-Webster]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than size-advantageousness, could I suggest benefit-of-scale. I would use it as:

> There is a benefit-of-scale to the policy, such it helps large communities much more than small communities.

Definitions from dictionary.reference.com:

> **[benefit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benefit?s=t)** - something that is advantageous or good; an advantage
>
> **[scale](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scale?s=t)** - a certain relative or proportionate size or extent